# Jquery function works in Firefox but does not work in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this function written in jquery.

```
var str1 = "This is a sample text";
var url = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + str1;
self.downloadURL(url);
```

here is the 'downloadUrl' function definition:

```
  self.downloadURL = function (url) {
            var iframe = $("#hiddenDownloader");
        if (iframe.length == 0) {
            iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                id: "hiddenDownloader",
                style: {
                    display: 'none'
                }
            }).appendTo(document.body);
        }               
        $(iframe).attr("src", url); // i guess this line is the culprit.       
    }
```

This functionality works fine in Firefox, by opening a "Open/Save" dialog box to open/save the given text in the local machine.

But, it does not work in IE 9, **No error, No response**. just keeps quiet.

Comment: change $(iframe).attr("src",url) to iframe.attr("src",url) only and try.

Comment: Why are you passing a plain object as the context in the `$('<iframe/>'...` call?

Comment: @maverickosama92 no luck

Comment: do you having any errors in console???

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I am finding an option to download the given text to local machine through jquery. it works fine in firefox but not in IE now.

Comment: 'self' is just the 'this' object, i mean it refers to the current object i am working on.

Comment: Can we have a look at the entire picture? A [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) would be great.

Comment: @maverickosama92 No error, it just keeps queit in IE 9.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta i have setup JSBin for this funtionality, http://jsbin.com/ucoKoCO/3/edit but it does not work in both IE and firefox now. All i see is a dummy frame added to the document. But, it works fine in firefox for me in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Checking on SO it appears that you should probably be trying to modify the location directly, rather than the attribute or the iframe.

Like so:

```
iframe[0].contentWindow.location.href = url;
```

**EDIT**

Not a bug, but a security feature apparently: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx

Look at the 3rd comment on that page:

> The restriction that DATA URIs cannot be navigated to (e.g. cannot be
>   used as the source of an IFRAME) remains in place.

Comment: is that working for you if you got a chance to test it? but it does not work for me.

Comment: Nope, I took a stab at answering the question. Evidently it is wrong, I can't open any data uri's in IE10. Copy and paste your uri into the location bar and see what happens - I get a unknown protocol error. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that data URIs are not allowed to populate iframes in IE, due to security restrictions. Also, IE can behave weirdly when you insert iframes into the DOM without setting a src attribute first. Try this, from http://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/:

```
 var newIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 newIframe.width = '200';newIframe.height = '200';
 newIframe.src = 'about:blank'; 
 document.body.appendChild(newIframe);

 var myContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
        + '<html><head><title>My dynamic document</head>'
        + '<body><p>Hello world</p></body></html>';

newIframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/html', 'replace');
newIframe.contentWindow.document.write(myContent);
newIframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: You have to set the src attribute and append it to the DOM before accessing it.